# How to write a query for this scenario

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like below in PostgreSQL.

```
+-------+--------+----------+--------+
|id     | name   |  rate    | amount |
+-------+--------+----------+--------+
|123    | Flat   |          | 40     |
|123    | weekly | 200      |        |
+-------+--------+----------+--------+
```

I need to show amount when its flat and rate when its weekly in the 'name' column. Expecting output like this:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| id    | name  |  rate     | amount |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
| 123   | 40    |           | 40     |
| 123   | 200   | 200       |        |
+-------+-------+-----------+--------+
```

Is it doable in PostgreSQL. If yes, how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html) expression:

```
SELECT id, CASE WHEN name = 'Flat' THEN amount ELSE rate END AS name, rate, amount
FROM mytable
```

Comment: select eng.id, et.name , cwd.week_num, cwd.rate, cwd.amount, et.id engagement_type_id
from engagement eng
left join reporting.vw_scale_deal vsd
on eng.id = vsd.engagement_id
join lookups.engagement_type et
on et.id = eng.engagement_type_id
left join engagement_contract_weekly_detail cwd
on eng.id = cwd.engagement_id
where cwd.week_num = 1
and case when et.name in ('Scale Terms', 'Flat Billing') then cwd.week_num else 1 end
      = 1 
and case when et.name in ('Weekly Percentage') then  cwd.rate else cwd.amount end

Comment: my whole query looks like this and it gives me error:   argument of AND must be type boolean, not type numeric

Comment: the last part of your query `case when et.name in ('Weekly Percentage') then cwd.rate else cwd.amount end` evaluates to a numeric, but you need a boolean

Comment: Any idea how to do that. sorry I am new to postgre SQL.

Comment: it sounds like you are having trouble with writing a basic select statements. please read about it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html)